# React Native with Expo fails on Android Emulator - Couldn't find implementation for Permissions Interface

Tags: android, react-native, expo

I'm trying to run one react-native app on the Android Emulator but the app shows this error after it launches.

[image: Couldn't find implementation for Permissions Interface]

It's not clear for me if it's complaining about the Android's Permission or if it comes from expo-permissions declared as dependency from other expo libs like expo-av and expo-image-picker.

Would you help me please?

Here's the build.gradle

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "29.0.3"
        minSdkVersion = 24
        compileSdkVersion = 30
        targetSdkVersion = 30
        // androidXAnnotation = "1.1.0"
        // androidXBrowser = "1.0.0"
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
        }
        maven {
            // Android JSC is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/jsc-android/dist")
        }
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
        maven { url 'https://www.jitpack.io' }
        maven {
            // expo-camera bundles a custom com.google.android:cameraview
            url "$rootDir/../node_modules/expo-camera/android/maven"
        }
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

and here's the dependencies:

```
{
  "name": "Instadating",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-native start",
    "prettier": "prettier --write '*.js' 'src/**/*.js'",
    "android": " cd android && ./gradlew clean && cd .. && react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "lint": "eslint src/.",
    "fixlint": "eslint --fix src/.; exit 0",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@invertase/react-native-apple-authentication": "^1.1.1",
    "@react-native-community/art": "^1.2.0",
    "@react-native-community/async-storage": "^1.6.3",
    "@react-native-community/geolocation": "^2.0.2",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.10",
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "^11.2.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/auth": "^11.2.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/messaging": "^11.2.0",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^5.7.0",
    "@react-navigation/compat": "^5.2.0",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^5.8.5",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^5.7.0",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.7.0",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.0.4",
    "axios": "^0.19.0",
    "base-64": "^0.1.0",
    "crypto-js": "^3.1.9-1",
    "expo-av": "^9.0.0",
    "expo-blur": "^9.0.0",
    "expo-camera": "^10.0.0",
    "expo-constants": "^10.0.1",
    "expo-facebook": "^10.0.0",
    "expo-file-system": "^10.0.0",
    "expo-firebase-recaptcha": "^1.3.0",
    "expo-image-picker": "^10.0.0",
    "expo-localization": "^10.0.0",
    "expo-location": "^11.0.0",
    "firebase": "8.3.2",
    "i18n-js": "^3.5.0",
    "invert-color": "^2.0.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "lodash.isequal": "^4.5.0",
    "lodash.memoize": "^4.1.2",
    "moment": "^2.27.0",
    "oauth-1.0a": "^2.2.6",
    "react": "17.0.1",
    "react-native": "0.64.0",
    "react-native-actionsheet": "^2.4.2",
    "react-native-app-intro-slider": "^4.0.4",
    "react-native-appearance": "^0.3.4",
    "react-native-autogrow-textinput": "^5.4.0",
    "react-native-button": "^3.0.1",
    "react-native-confirmation-code-field": "^6.5.0",
    "react-native-create-thumbnail": "^1.2.2",
    "react-native-deck-swiper": "^2.0.5",
    "react-native-dialog-input": "^1.0.8",
    "react-native-elements": "^2.3.1",
    "react-native-fast-image": "^8.3.2",
    "react-native-ffmpeg": "^0.5.0",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.7.0",
    "react-native-get-random-values": "^1.4.0",
    "react-native-iap": "^6.0.2",
    "react-native-image-crop-picker": "^0.33.2",
    "react-native-image-picker": "^2.3.3",
    "react-native-image-progress": "^1.1.1",
    "react-native-image-resizer": "^1.2.6",
    "react-native-image-view": "^2.1.9",
    "react-native-indicators": "^0.17.0",
    "react-native-iphone-x-helper": "^1.2.1",
    "react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "^0.9.2",
    "react-native-keyboard-aware-view": "^0.0.14",
    "react-native-keyboard-tracking-view": "^5.7.0",
    "react-native-localize": "^1.3.1",
    "react-native-modal": "^11.4.0",
    "react-native-modal-patch": "https://github.com/HarvestProfit/react-native-modal-patch.git",
    "react-native-modalbox": "^2.0.0",
    "react-native-phone-input": "^0.2.4",
    "react-native-progress": "^4.1.2",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^1.13.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^3.1.7",
    "react-native-screens": "^2.10.1",
    "react-native-scrollable-tab-view": "^0.10.0",
    "react-native-search-bar": "^3.5.1",
    "react-native-search-box": "^0.0.19",
    "react-native-slider": "^0.11.0",
    "react-native-splash-screen": "^3.2.0",
    "react-native-swiper": "^1.6.0",
    "react-native-ui-lib": "^5.19.0",
    "react-native-unimodules": "^0.11.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^7.0.0",
    "react-native-video": "^5.1.0-alpha8",
    "react-native-view-overflow": "^0.0.5",
    "react-native-webview": "^10.8.3",
    "react-redux": "^7.1.1",
    "redux": "^4.0.4",
    "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "remote-redux-devtools": "^0.5.16",
    "uuidv4": "^5.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.8.4",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.8.4",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^1.1.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.0.3",
    "babel-jest": "^25.1.0",
    "eslint": "^4.3.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^17.1.0",
    "eslint-config-idiomatic": "^4.0.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^4.3.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.17.3",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.2.1",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.13.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-native": "^3.7.0",
    "jest": "^25.1.0",
    "jetifier": "^1.6.6",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.59.0",
    "prettier": "2.0.4",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.13.1"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

Thanks in Advance :)

Comment: Did you figure out a fix for this?

Answer (score 1):

I have similar problem. I think you missed "expo install" (to link the expo and run module) the project before running it.

you could try: `npm install -> expo install -> npx react-native run-android`.

If it still doesn't work, you may try `npm start -- --reset-cache` to clean the cache for run and run it.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem after I installed `expo-image-picker` with version `10.*`, downgrade to version `9.*` helped me to fix it.

You'll have to update even your `build.gradle` to

```
buildscript {
ext {
    buildToolsVersion = "29.0.3"
    minSdkVersion = 21
    compileSdkVersion = 29
    targetSdkVersion = 29
}
...
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me - I'm on 9.* of expo-image-picker, and my buildscript has higher versions of everything - "30.0.2", 30, etc. So I'm not sure why I am seeing this same error

Answer (score 0):

This is very likely caused by the version of `expo-permissions` that you're using. I ran into this issue after I ran npm-check-updates and it updated `expo-permissions` and `expo-image-picker`.

When I dropped back to these two versions (left column), everything worked well again:

```
 expo-image-picker        ^10.1.4  →  ^10.2.2     
 expo-permissions         ^12.0.1  →  ^12.1.1
```